# Rsync folders automatization

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, sync, rsync

I've got a folder on the remote server, to which I'm connecting via SSH.
When I need to synchronise folders I'm using manually access via scp. (I'm synchronising my folder with the folder on the server.)

How can I setup this job to be done automatically by some script or so, so it automatically synchronises folders and automatically insert password?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH without a password is usually done with [public key authentication](http://micheljansen.org/blog/entry/123). Normally you would encrypt the private key with a password, however since you want to run an unattended syncing script I'd recommend you create the keys as another user and run the shell script as that user.

On client:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -q -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa
# Press enter twice when asked for a passphrase
```

Since Mac's don't have SSH Copy Id you need to do it's work manually:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server.example.com:~
```

On server

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
# Append or copy public key to authorized keys file:
cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
rm ~/id_rsa.pub
```

A [shell script](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a text file with executable permission set that begins with

```
#!/bin/sh
# you can then do any commands that you do manually, ex:
# (See levy's answer for the rsync command to use)
rsync /home/Anders/ 192.168.3.5:~/backup/location
```

To do execute a script periodically you can use [cron](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_cron_jobs). Say we saved that script in /home/Anders/bin/sync.sh. You'd then run:

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

as the user you want to run the cron script as.

In the text editor that appears you'd enter:

```
#Minute Hour  Day Month Year  Command  
0        13   *   *     *     /home/Anders/bin/sync.sh
```

The above would sync every day on the 0th minute of the 14th hour (it starts counting from zero), adjust to your needs.

Another option could be [SSHFS](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/acts/2013/11/08/the-newbie-how-to-set-up-sshfs-on-mac-os-x/) That is, you'd mount it and you can operate on it as a normal directory.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to rsync without a password you are going to need to create ssh private and public keys. And paste your public key in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file in your remote server. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host # you could also just login and create the authorized_keys file and paste your public key. 
ssh remote-host
```

For the `rsync -avz --delete -e ssh ~/dir/ user@server:/home/dir`

I use the --delete to make sure everything is always the same, but remove if you do not want to do that. At this point put the rsync command into a bash script and put it in cron or do a run when you feel like it.